# CRC code and implementation compatibility

Tags: c, embedded

the mechanism or the steps for the CRC checksum is easy , but the software is somehow much [complicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi5ZN.png) and there are some steps in software that are not compatible with the steps of CRC
the following picture is the steps for getting the checksum of the CRC ( which is simply a modulo 2 division):

the checksum is the remainder = 001
the software for calculating the CRC checksum is for a string of bits is:

```
/*
 * The width of the CRC calculation and result.
 * Modify the typedef for a 16 or 32-bit CRC standard.
 */
typedef uint8_t crc;

#define WIDTH  (8 * sizeof(crc))
#define TOPBIT (1 << (WIDTH - 1))

crc
crcSlow(uint8_t const message[], int nBytes)
{
    crc  remainder = 0; 


    /*
     * Perform modulo-2 division, a byte at a time.
     */
    for (int byte = 0; byte < nBytes; ++byte)
    {
        /*
         * Bring the next byte into the remainder.
         */
        remainder ^= (message[byte] << (WIDTH - 8));

        /*
         * Perform modulo-2 division, a bit at a time.
         */
        for (uint8_t bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            /*
             * Try to divide the current data bit.
             */
            if (remainder & TOPBIT)
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            }
            else
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * The final remainder is the CRC result.
     */
    return (remainder);

}
```

I see that there is incompatibility in the software in the `part( remainder<<1 )` because the shifting will always add 0 at the right even if the following bit is not 0.

and also in the part: 
`remainder ^= (message[byte] << (WIDTH - 8));`

when putting the first byte I don't see problem because the initial value is because the initial value is 0, but when inserting the next bytes why we xor every byte of them with the previous remainder

Comment: There is no **the** CRC. There are very different CRC algorithms. Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: What is a "modulo 2 division"? CRCs are not. There are some good articles desribing the idea of CRCs and their implementations. And you still should read [ask]! Oh, and your code can invoke undefined behaviour for certain combinations of sizese of `int` and `crc`.

Answer (score 0):

The code example appears to use a variable sized CRC, where the size of the CRC is WIDTH. POLYNOMIAL is the bottom WIDTH bits of a WIDTH+1 bit polynomial, which will have the least significant bit set to 1. Since the operations are XOR, the order in which the data bits are XOR'ed into the remainder doesn't matter, so 8 data bits can be XOR'ed into the upper bits of remainder at the same time. Then the bit at a time feedback cycle occurs for 8 bits. Since the bottom bit of POLYNOMIAL is a 1, that will keep the cycle going, as long as there are any 1 bits in the data.